# Add multiple Elements to Set in a Dictionary

Tags: python, graph, set

I am trying to achieve the following structure.

```
{0: set([1]), 1: set([2]), 2: set([0,3]), 3: set([3])}
```

Following is my code :

```
class Graph(object):
    """ This is the graph class which will store the information regarding
        the graph like vertices and edges.
    """

    def __init__(self,num_vertices):
        self.vertices = num_vertices
        self.edges = []
        self.indi_edges = ()

    def enter_edges(self,source,dest):
        self.indi_edges = (source, dest)
        self.edges.append(self.indi_edges)

    def form_graph_structure(self):
        temp_dict = {}
        for idx,value in enumerate(self.edges):
            if value[0] in temp_dict:
                print "here"
                temp_dict[value[0]].update(value[1])
            print "there"
            temp_dict[value[0]] = set()
            temp_dict[value[0]].add(value[1])
        print temp_dict


    def display(self):
        print self.edges

g = Graph(4)
g.enter_edges(2,0)
g.enter_edges(2,3)
g.enter_edges(0,1)
g.enter_edges(1,2)
g.enter_edges(3,3)
g.form_graph_structure()
```

I am getting the following error

```
  File "DFS.py", line 20, in form_graph_structure
    temp_dict[value[0]].update(value[1])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) using `set` as its default value.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph(object):
    """ This is the graph class which will store the information regarding
        the graph like vertices and edges.
    """

    def __init__(self, num_vertices):
        self.vertices = num_vertices
        self.edges = []

    def enter_edges(self, source, dest):
        self.edges.extend([(source, dest)])

    def form_graph_structure(self):
        temp_dict = defaultdict(set)
        for pair in self.edges:
            source, dest = pair
            temp_dict[source].add(dest)
        print temp_dict

    def display(self):
        print dict(self.edges)

g = Graph(4)
g.enter_edges(2,0)
g.enter_edges(2,3)
g.enter_edges(0,1)
g.enter_edges(1,2)
g.enter_edges(3,3)

>>> g.form_graph_structure()
{0: set([1]), 1: set([2]), 2: set([0, 3]), 3: set([3])}
```

You could also update the graph structure after entering each pair of edges:

```
class Graph(object):
    """ This is the graph class which will store the information regarding
        the graph like vertices and edges.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(set)

    def enter_edges(self, source, dest):
        self.graph[source].add(dest)

    def display(self):
        print dict(self.graph)

g = Graph()
edges = [(2, 0), (2, 3), (0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)]
for pair in edges:
    g.enter_edges(*pair)
g.display()
{0: set([1]), 1: set([2]), 2: set([0, 3]), 3: set([3])}
```

Answer (score 3):

`set.update()` expects an *iterable* of values. Use [`set.add()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.add) to add *one* value:

```
if value[0] in temp_dict:
    temp_dict[value[0]].add(value[1])
```

Rather than test for `value[0]` each time, use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set an empty set if the key is missing:

```
def form_graph_structure(self):
    temp_dict = {}
    for source, dest in self.edges:
        temp_dict.setdefault(source, set()).add(dest)
    return temp_dict
```